# PyTorch Factorial Function

Tags: python, math, deep-learning, pytorch

There does not seem to be a PyTorch function for computing a factorial. Is there a method to do this in PyTorch? I am looking to manually compute a Poisson distribution in Torch (I am aware this exists: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.poisson.html) and the formula requires a factorial in the denominator.

Poisson Distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136447/function-for-factorial-in-python

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I can use a combination of Torch functions to compute a factorial exclusively in Torch.

Comment: Doesn't `lgamma` give you what you need? (In combination with `exp`, obviously, though you may do better to keep things in log form until right at the end anyway.)

Comment: lngamma is the right answer.  it's a better idea than naive undergraduate recursive implementations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can find it as `torch.jit._builtins.math.factorial` **BUT** `pytorch` as well as `numpy` and `scipy` ([Factorial in numpy and scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753913/10749432)) uses `python`'s builtin `math.factorial`:

```py
import math

import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import torch


print(torch.jit._builtins.math.factorial is math.factorial)
print(np.math.factorial is math.factorial)
print(sp.math.factorial is math.factorial)
```

```py
True
True
True
```

But, in contrast, `scipy` in addition to "mainstream" `math.factorial` contains the very "special" factorial function `scipy.special.factorial`. Unlike function from `math` module it operates on arrays:

```py
from scipy import special

print(special.factorial is math.factorial)
```

```py
False
```

```py
# the all known factorial functions
factorials = (
    math.factorial,
    torch.jit._builtins.math.factorial,
    np.math.factorial,
    sp.math.factorial,
    special.factorial,
)

# Let's run some tests
tnsr = torch.tensor(3)

for fn in factorials:
    try:
        out = fn(tnsr)
    except Exception as err:
        print(fn.__name__, fn.__module__, ':', err)
    else:
        print(fn.__name__, fn.__module__, ':', out)
```

```py
factorial math : 6
factorial math : 6
factorial math : 6
factorial math : 6
factorial scipy.special._basic : tensor(6., dtype=torch.float64)
```

```py
tnsr = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])

for fn in factorials:
    try:
        out = fn(tnsr)
    except Exception as err:
        print(fn.__name__, fn.__module__, ':', err)
    else:
        print(fn.__name__, fn.__module__, ':', out)
```

```py
factorial math : only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
factorial math : only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
factorial math : only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
factorial math : only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
factorial scipy.special._basic : tensor([1., 2., 6.], dtype=torch.float64)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`torch.lgamma`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.lgamma.html) computes the log of the gamma which is equal to (x-1)!

```py
import torch

def log_factorial(x):
  return torch.lgamma(x + 1)

def factorial(x):
  return torch.exp(log_factorial(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The built in `math` module ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html)) provides a function that returns the factorial of a given integral as an `int`.

```py
import math

x = math.factorial(5)
print(x)
print(type(x))
```

**Output**

```
120
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was aware of other methods to compute a factorial in Python. I was looking for a method using exclusively PyTorch.

Comment: @kjans_tbme Oh I see, apologies for my misunderstanding. To the best of my knowledge there is not a factorial function within the PyTorch library - with the exception of `TorchScript` ([docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html)) which itself makes the built in `math` module and `math.factorial` available.