# A density plot in the Poisson distribution

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I need to draw a density plot of the Poisson distribution and a histogram of the selection, but a given error occurs which I have no idea how to solve

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lam = 3  # Параметр распределения Пуассона (лямбда)
x = np.arange(0, 20)

# Вычисление значений плотности распределения Пуассона
y = np.exp(-lam) * (lam ** x) / np.math.factorial(x)

# Построение графика
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', ms=8)  # 'bo' - голубые круглые маркеры

plt.xlabel("Значение СВ")
plt.ylabel("Плотность")

plt.title("Распределение Пуассона")
plt.show()
```

I tried to replace `x` with `np.array(x)`, but it didn't lead to anything

Comment: What do you expect from `np.math.factorial([0, 1, ...., 19])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```py
y = np.exp(-lam) * (lam ** x) / np.math.factorial(x)
```

you should iterate over the values of x, therefore try this:

```py
y = [np.exp(-lam) * (lam ** i) / np.math.factorial(i) for i in x]
```

The rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Ugur's anwser, you need to vectorize the factorial function (very unusual inside numpy's package). Also for a bar plot, you must use `plt.bar`:

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

lam = 3  # Параметр распределения Пуассона (лямбда)
x = np.arange(0, 20)

# Вычисление значений плотности распределения Пуассона
y = np.exp(-lam) * (lam ** x) / np.vectorize(np.math.factorial)(x)

# Построение графика
plt.bar(x, y)  # 'bo' - голубые круглые маркеры

plt.xlabel("Значение СВ")
plt.ylabel("Плотность")

plt.title("Распределение Пуассона")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21753913/12131013), `np.math.factorial` and `scipy.math.factorial` are just aliases to `math.factorial`, which does not work with numpy arrays. Instead, use [`scipy.special.factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html), which can work with numpy arrays.

```py
from scipy.special import factorial

x = np.arange(0, 20)

# other code here

y = np.exp(-lam)*(lam**x)/factorial(x)

# plotting code here
```

[image]